# How to solve Github Action: Configure-aws-credentials: Could not load credentials from any providers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, cicd

I setup the actions:

```
name: Deploy Serverless Application
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: ["master"]
permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: write
  packages: write
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: dev
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "14" # Specify the Node.js version you are using
      - name: Install Serverless
        run: npm install -g serverless
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: eu-north-1 # Replace with your AWS region
      - name: Deploy to AWS
        run: |
          cd BE
          serverless deploy --stage ${{ github.event.inputs.stage || 'dev' }}
```

I checked that AWS IAM has all permissions:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

yet every time i deploy i get the same error on the  Configure AWS credentials step. What am i missing?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN61X.png

Comment: Have you set your repository secrets on GitHub ?

Comment: @ErikPartila yes I have done that, 5 times

Comment: Maybe try to use newer version of composite action (v4):
uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v4